# Looping through an array to get the data for specific

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to loop through an array of objects to get a specific id and then render its data in a component in react, why it cannot be mapped, what is wrong here?

```
const projectData = projects.find(element => {
  return element.id === projectId;
});
return (
  {projectData.map(project => {
    return <ProjectData key={project.id} {...project}></ProjectData>;
  })}
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` is returning either `null` or an object. you need an array to loop over the map. use the `filter` operator instead

```
const projectData = projects.filter(element => {
  return element.id === projected;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `find()` method returns **the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.** If no values satisfy the testing function, `undefined` is returned.

So you don't need to use `map` for rendering.

```
const projectData = projects.find(element => {
  return element.id === projectId;
});
return (
 {projectData && <ProjectData key={projectData.id} {...projectData}></ProjectData>}
)
```

If there are many elements that satisfies the **testing function** please use the `filter` method, not `find` method.
In this case, the return value is the array, so you should use `map` for rendering.

```
const projectData = projects.filter(element => {
  return element.id === projectId;
});
return (
  {projectData.map(project => {
    return <ProjectData key={project.id} {...project}></ProjectData>;
  })}
)
```